# Adding numeric value based on tickbox in Sharepoint formula

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create a simple leave planner application using Sharepoint. I've got the bulk of it working but I'm going back to do edge cases now like Bank Holidays and half days. So I've added a checkbox column and if ticked, I want it to deduct 0.5 from the total value (half-day). The formula that's working for the full days is:

```
=(DATEDIF(dateFrom,dateTo,"D"))-INT(DATEDIF(dateFrom,dateTo,"D")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY(dateTo)-WEEKDAY(dateFrom))<0,2,0)+1
```

So I just created another two columns called shalfday and ehalfday. If they're ticked then deduct 0.5 from the total (If dates match and both ticked then deduct 0.5 still).

I've tried playing round with things like

```
-IF([shalfday],"0.5")
```

and other variants as google results are not being too kind this morning but they're returning #NAME? variables.

Any pointers on the syntax or what I should be looking at?

Comment: as and advice: your "Sharepoint formula" is actually equal to an 'Excel formula'. So open Excel and simulate your calculated field columns there. It will be a lot easier to 'debug' the formula

Comment: Hi,I used the same formula in Excel (just not bound to a checkbox name). The formula does actually take away the 0.5 where I need it do. Sharepoint just seems to have real difficulty in knowing what I'm trying.    I tried appending the code Nils provided below to the end of the working day formula above but still get the #NAME? reference.....All I'm trying to do is say if checkbox=true then -0.5 from result. Seems really obtuse on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this another way. I instead asked the user to specify how many half days were in their leave in another site column and used this suffix in the formula. It also got rid of the validation check to make sure the user wasn't taking two half days on 1 days leave.

**New site column called 'Total Half Days'** set to number, default value of 0;
Appended to original formula:

```
-([Total Half Days]/2)+1
```

Full formula:

```
=(DATEDIF(dateFrom,dateTo,"D"))-INT(DATEDIF(dateFrom,dateTo,"D")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY(dateTo)-WEEKDAY(dateFrom))<0,2,0)-([Total Half Days]/2)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
-IF([shalfday],0.5,0)
```

Since you are trying to subtract you should work with integers and not strings (i removed the quotation marks).